# agrupar fechas por cantidad de días

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer agrupamiento de una consulta a la tabla de ventas para obtener un gráfico como el que se muestra [aqui](https://demo.improvely.com/reports/webshop/overview) :

[image: Imagen que quiero obtener]

Pero no tengo idea de cómo hacer para sumarle 2 días a la fecha, partiendo de hace 30 días hasta llegar a la fecha actual. Se grafica el último mes de ventas.

Intenté con ésto, pero obviamente está mal, crea un lazo y nunca itera la suma.

```
GO  
WHILE (select fecha) <= (select getdate())
BEGIN  
    select DATEADD (day, 2, (select DATEADD(month,-1, getdate()))) as fecha
END
```

¿Cómo se hace eso?

Los datos que obtengo:

```
20190207    317506754.9645520015
20190208    451709300.8099469876
20190209    295704231.2037169916
20190210    239238666.4012149778
20190211    218128916.6722139870
20190212    248990937.8454129970
20190213    251092028.4852610083
20190214    440700342.0264910007
20190215    316978860.7280419851
20190216    272800311.6998089824
20190217    205993618.6754000169
20190218    169064202.1723799990
20190219    249563783.2601310055
20190220    176287962.3500029941
20190221    217856557.3763929950
20190222    233178088.7283479973
20190223    260739431.8946959949
20190224    207439048.9767830239
20190225    157983615.4923169944
20190226    171923034.8937829950
20190227    288423593.6919339899
20190228    310591473.1194680045
20190301    356610450.2629069987
20190302    295515461.9163500022
20190303    233913203.1487470118
20190304    137276850.4486070049
20190305    140681886.6527199944
20190306    118368250.3859499969
20190307    97090095.5693399932
```

Como deseo obtenerlos:

```
20190207    317506754.9645520015    
20190209    295704231.2037169916    
20190211    218128916.6722139870    
20190213    251092028.4852610083    
20190215    316978860.7280419851    
20190217    205993618.6754000169    
20190219    249563783.2601310055    
20190221    217856557.3763929950    
20190223    260739431.8946959949    
20190225    157983615.4923169944    
20190227    288423593.6919339899    
20190301    356610450.2629069987    
20190303    233913203.1487470118    
20190305    140681886.6527199944    
20190307    97090095.5693399932
```

Cada dos días

Comment: Por favor, si tenes una imagen de ejemplo tiene que ir en la pregunta. Ademas mostra los datos de entrada y como queres que queden los datos de salida

Comment: o sea, solo queres mostrar dias impares?

Comment: ESto va a tener un problema los 29 de febrero ;) porque tenes 2 dias impares juntos.. y los 31 tambien... como queres hacer en ese caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para "sumarle 2 días a la fecha, partiendo de hace 30 días hasta llegar a la fecha actual."

```
declare @fecha date
declare @dias table (dia date)


set  @fecha  = dateadd(dd,-30, getdate());

while (@fecha < getdate() )
begin 

    --select @fecha
    insert into @dias values (@fecha)
    set  @fecha  = dateadd(dd,2, @fecha); --agregamos 2 días a cada fecha

end

select * from @dias
```

Comment: Gracias @patovega justo lo que necesitaba